# Why can't we use websocket in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, asynchronous

Reference is this one:http://www.slideshare.net/Typesafe_Inc/why-play-framework-is-fast

In page 17 in the slide I showed through the link, there is a brief summary about Thread per Request Model.
And they say "Useful for ThreadLocal" as an advantage, but why?
I think it is possible even though we are on other systems.
And disadvantage is like this:

If the request is kept open, the thread has to wait until it closes or gives data.
This means cannot use Websocket, SSE, Comet, and etc.

I can't understand it well.  In the client side, if we write an appropriate code written in JavaScript for asynchronous connection, we can realize it, can't we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. From the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html):

> Tomcat implements the Java WebSocket 1.1 API defined by JSR-356.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.         "If the request is kept open, the thread has to wait until it closes or gives data. This means cannot use Websocket, SSE, Comet, and etc."           What does it mean?     The connection for the asymmetric connection by SSE or Websocket etc  is through another a connection, so I assume it has something strange because the request should be different.